# 2.78 broke all of my files' texture rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

My first time posting here. I have a whole bunch of files, all of them are set up pretty similarly, with the only difference between them being a cube size and the texture applied to it. Anyway, the files work fine in 2.76 and before, but are borken in 2.78 and later.

None of the settings have changed, and I can't figure out from the patch notes what may have changed that would just break everything like that.

The probelm really shows up on render; I use Cycles render, same as before, and it just renders everything as gray. Having rendered all of these files several times on 2.76 I know that the lights and such are as I want them. And, if I reinstall 2.76, everything works normally again, same files.

Here is a sample file linked below, and I'm also posting what the image actually looks like in 2.77a. I would be EVER-SO-GRATEFUL if anyone can help me figure this out.

[image]

Lighting Rig: [image]

Properly rendered:

[image: properly rendered image]

Rendering in 2.79a:
[image: 2.79a rendered image]

Lighting:
[image: properly rendered image]

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to add your .blend file to your question.

Comment: There you go, thanks, sorry didn't know about that.

Answer (score 3):

The real issue is that the subdivision surface modifier on the main plane is set to a different value between preview and render:

[image]

Additionally, the way Dupvertex interprets object scaling has been changed in 2.79. The best way to move forward is to scale the 'pixel' cube into a square and then apply the scale with Ctrl+A:

[image]

Finally, adjust the bevel modifier to get the right amount of bevel again.

Comment: Hi @mike, Thanks for looking! No, the image definitely has lights, all grouped under lighting.rig.002. There are 7 or 8 and they're working. Anyway, the image that you're showing is exhibiting the same problems on my screen in Blender 2.78 and .79, and that's the preview render, but I can already tell that you'll be able to reproduce the issue. If you F12 that, you'll see what I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: just downloaded the file to make sure it was uploaded correctly, and it was. I'm posting a screenshot of the lighting rig to the OP. If you zoom out of the view when open and rotate a bit you'll see it as well. :)

Comment: Can you check my answer now? It should be fixed for F12 render.

Comment: OMG, thank you! This is such a step in the right direction! Ok, so 1: I've uploaded the linked light rig, which I'm sorry I didn't think to include before. 2: Your solution about the View and Preview settings defo fixes the problem of the file just rendering gray but it still is really messed up. Reverting to 2.77 without any changes goes back to totally normal. Attaching that image to the OP, also. And THANK YOU! I was totally ready to give up on this. Truly, truly appreciate it!

Comment: See edit. Always 'Apply Scale', this will save you a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mike! I will try this as soon as possible! :)